# Tree w/multiple Roots

Tags: extjs, tree

Does anyone have an example how to add multiple Root Nodes to TreePanel? I'm looking to usethe TreePanel like a ListTree? User Privs would determine which Root Nodes get displayed as well as what Clubs get shown...

For Example:

- Clubs (Root Node)
- Club 1
- Club N
- Jr Clubs (Root Node)
- Club Jr 1
- Club Jr N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root is the root. You can't have many roots. You just need to add one root to your example and specify `rootVisible: false`, this way you don't see but see exactly what you shown.

Comment: Yes, buts a requirement from client that in json while editing each root should have different name, so that it will be easy to catch and edit

Comment: And what's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: I am trying it, but as I am new to extjs, i dont know how to apply  multiple roots in extjs for treepanel. as per example i provide.